# React.js Navbar Hamburger Menu won't toggle closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So, I have a react.js app built with a group. Our Navbar works, but when the Navbar is toggled from a smaller screen using the Hamburger menu, it will open, but the toggle doesn't work to close it, it stays stuck open. I didn't program this page, but I've been trying to debug why it won't close, and for what I can see, it should work.

Yes, I know react.bootstrap is a thing, and I was thinking about converting it, but I'm on a deadline and don't want to rewrite this entire component from scratch if it is at all possible. Any thoughts, or suggestions. I thought it was likely in the toggleNav function, but from what I've tested it seems to be correct.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";

class Nav extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    width: window.innerWidth,
  };

  updateWidth = () => {
    const newState = { width: window.innerWidth };

    if (this.state.open && newState.width > 991) {
      newState.open = false;
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  };

  toggleNav = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  setActiveNavItem = (path) => {
    return window.location.pathname === path ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          Seenit
        </Link>
        <button
          onClick={this.toggleNav}
          className="navbar-toggler"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>
        <div
          className={`${this.state.open ? "" : "collapse "}navbar-collapse`}
          id="navbarNav"
        >
          {/* Navbar items */}
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                onClick={this.toggleNav}
                className={this.setActiveNavItem("/")}
                to="/"
              >
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                onClick={this.toggleNav}
                className={this.setActiveNavItem("/create-post")}
                to="/create-post"
              >
                Create a Post
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                onClick={this.toggleNav}
                className={this.setActiveNavItem("/log-in")}
                to="/log-in"
              >
                Log In
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                onClick={this.toggleNav}
                className={this.setActiveNavItem("/sign-up")}
                to="/sign-up"
              >
                Sign Up
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This React component is a direct implementation of the [Bootstrap Toggler Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#toggler).

Unfortunately, this component also contains code that modifies the navbar, which almost certainly breaks the Bootstrap code that controls collapsible navbars.

Here is the pure HTML version of this navbar component. Note that it collapses to a hamburger on narrow screens (as desired).

It should be straightforward to remove from this component the code that modifies the Bootstrap Toggler navbar.

```css
.navbar {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body class="p-2">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light mr-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Seenit</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Create a Post</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- JS required for Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but is a solution. I'm just having to decide how to re-write as we are using all React, so just straight Html will work in the return. I still will have to re-structure the file either way, so I see what is up. Thanks!!

Comment: @BrianAllen This HTML is literally what your react code produces